# Docker: WSL 2 integration with distro Ubuntu 20.04 unexpectedly stopped with exit code 1

Tags: wsl-2, docker-desktop

My docker environment was working fine. I restarted my system and it stopped unexpectedly. whenever I try to start docker it throws the following error

> WSL 2 integration with distro Ubuntu 20.04 unexpectedly stopped with exit code 1.

I am using the following versions

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop 4.6.1
- WSL 2
- List item
- .wslconfig (memory=8GB, processors=4)

I have tried following patterns to make it run

- restarted docker and windows many times
- done with wsl upgrade > sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

Comment: Is the Ubuntu WSL distribution running fine otherwise (the last bullet indicates that it is)?  Typically this error will occur when the distribution terminates.  Also, have you changed anything in your shell startup scripts recently?  Not running Systemd, right?  After this error occurs, is the Ubuntu/WSL distribution still running (`wsl -l -v` from PowerShell)?

Comment: Wondering if this problem resolved itself for you.  It sounds now to me like it could have been caused by the bug mentioned in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401830/wsl-not-working-after-update-from-microsoft-store/1401946#1401946), *especially* since you mention specifically using the "Ubuntu 20.04" distro.  The problem was quickly resolved for most people with a new version pushed by Canonical, which I would assume would have happened for you.  For those unlucky few that first installed when the bug was in place, the "fix" broke things for them, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue when updated docker desktop with WSL2 backed has a work around I did the following steps:

1. In docker desktop settings i enabled again the "enabled integration with other distros"
2. Apply and restart the changes then stop Docker desktop.
3. Enter to Settings -> Apps and search for ubuntu
4. Click on Ubuntu and advanced settings
5. Select repair
6. Restart the computer
7. After computer starts enter to the ubuntu wsl via console or terminal
8. Start docker desktop
9. Try docker ps or docker-compose to check if the error was resolved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is from: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9972#issuecomment-756900017

Comment: I can't open docker desktop setting, it's also loading forever :(

Comment: Skipping to step 3 (since docker desktop was entirely frozen up) also worked for me. Also docker started by itself at launch so step 7-8 was also not necessary

Comment: The "Enter to Settings -> Apps and search for ubuntu" point refers to the Windows Settings app. For me it wasn't obvious, as I didn't know that there is a dedicated Settings app besides control panel

Answer (score 13):

Check for a system variable

```
Path - C:\Windows\System32
```

Maybe it will save you a few hours.

Comment: I can't believe this was the actual problem for me!  I was cleaning out my %PATH% variable since it had grown too large and had removed some duplicates. I removed `C:\Windows\System32` because `%SystemRoot%\System32` was already there, but apparently the variable expansion doesn't work correctly in Docker Desktop.

Comment: I upvote but this answer was not clear enough IMHO. This solution was the solution for a colleague. 
For some reason his Path variable went corrupted, so just ensure your Path variable (User and System) at least has the minimum entries : https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000088.htm

Comment: This worked for me but the answer not clear- Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables." Click "Edit the system environment variables."
In the System Properties window, click "Environment Variables."
Under the "System variables" section, select the "Path" variable.
Click "Edit" to modify the "Path" variable. In the "Edit Environment Variable" window, check if "C:\Windows\System32" is listed. If not, click "New" and add it manually (separate multiple entries with a semicolon).
Click "OK" to save the changes.

Answer (score 6):

Try these commands if you're willing to risk losing the data:

`wsl --unregister docker-desktop` 
`wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data`

Comment: This worked for me where nothing else worked. It deleted all the images and containers i had though

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the solutions here worked for me. Steps to fix were:

1. Update WSL2 Ubuntu distro:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

2. Uninstall Docker Desktop on Windows
3. Reinstall Docker Desktop on Windows

Note that containers and volumes were lost with the uninstall.

Comment: In my case just apt update upgrade is resolve problem

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem. It solved after I add 'C:\Windows\System32' to path.

Try type wsl.exe or wslconfig.exe /l. If nothing happens than modify the path.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution comes from [todpale](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9972#issuecomment-787076492):

1. close Docker Desktop
2. restart Ubuntu through services.msc or this command (you can put in bat):
   `net stop LxssManager && net start LxssManager`
3. start Docker again

You also may check if your distro is enabled in Docker settings (General tab and Resources tab -> WSL Integration).

There is a discussion about this issue on Github https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9972

Answer (score 1):

Just posting what worked for me. I was using a WSL distro that I restored from a previous Windows installation (named here `ubuntu-restore`).

Initially, I was able to get more information to debug my problem by running:

`sudo /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro proxy --distro-name ubuntu-restore`

And the console gave the following error (simplified):

```
[docker-desktop-user-distro in ubuntu-restore][I] mounting /mnt/c/Users/no-longer-exists to /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/ubuntu-restore/b34c91da7c9e60d4983f67b84fe84fda955dbf79d010eb25ab0aaec28012fb5c
[docker-desktop-user-distro in ubuntu-restore][W] restoreMounts: ensure ready failed: mkdir /mnt/c/Users/no-longer-exists: permission denied
```

Which meant I had to clean up some old bind mounts that stayed in the distro. I found them in `/var/lib/docker-desktop/mounts.data`, removed them, and the WSL integration works again.

Comment: That's the solution right there. I was working on a project which I had to simulate a serial connection and I used /dev/pts/<pts_number> and pts was created randomly, so it was mounted on mount.data but it was never created on WSL

Answer (score 1):

My user folder had `root:root` ownership.

I ran `sudo chown -R david:david david` (david is my username). So it was a permission issue.

Seems like there's a lot of reasons why this happens.

Comment: Thanks, chown worked for me, in my case I run sudo chown -R <<username>>: /home/<<username>>

Comment: Oh that was a typo my bad. Yes `chown` is correct. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried every answer here but when I'm starting docker was still facing the same issue.

So I started the docker without WSL after installation, then changed the setting to use WSL. Docker is working fine now. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times, and in many cases it was because I needed to update to a new version of **WSL** e.g. run the following in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> wsl --update
Checking for updates.
Updating Windows Subsystem for Linux.
PS C:\Users\Me> wsl -v -l
WSL version: 1.2.0.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2728
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error when Docker desktop was attempting to start.

Below are some attempts I made to resolve the issue with no outcome:

1. Try restart WSL2 - `wsl --shutdown`
2. Try update WSL2 - `wsl --update` & `wsl.exe --update --pre-release`
3. Restarting windows
4. Updating windows (lol)
5. Restarting the LsxxManager - `Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service`
6. Literally every solution shared [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9868)

> NB: All the above commands were run in Powershell with administrative rights.

After 2 days, this worked for me.

#### **Solution**: I removed the `.wslconfig` file I added to the path `C:\Users\<username>`

I added this file to limit the insane amounts of memory Docker was consuming on WSL2. More details [here](https://gist.github.com/apexDev37/4966dc17b1193d53c2fbf641136332f8)

After I updated Docker to `v4.18.0` it appears that the applied memory allocation constrained the new update from launching.
Once I deleted the `.wslconfig` file, Docker started smoothly.

Version details for my machine:

- Windows: `10 Pro - Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.2846)`
- WSL2: `1.2.1.0`
- Docker: `v4.18.0`

Answer (score 0):

My situation was that I move my WSL ext4.vhdx file to another PC. To resolve this issue I had to set a default user to WSL using this command because by default its root :

`ubuntu config --default-user <username>`

Answer (score 0):

In Docker Desktop Settings:

1. Go to [*Resources* -> *WSL integration*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26DkI.png)
2. Enable integration with additional distros
3. Select *Apply & restart*

If you get the error again just keep clicking restart.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem,  but this isn't likely to be the solution for most users.

Answer (score 0):

**tldr: Turn off Resource Saver when debugging**

I hope this helps someone avoid my pain...

While debugging the issue above, matter what I did,`docker ps` would output

```
We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit:

https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/
```

Then I turned off Resources->Advanced->Resource Saver in docker desktop and it fixed it.
[Screenshot of Docker Desktop settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jSqu.png)

My underlying issue was similar to Manuel Pacheco mounts, but when debugging with no containers running I found that Resource Saver would cause docker ps not to work even after I removed the mounts file.